# How do you check to see if a sprite collides with any other object (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine, collision

When the user touches the screen, a sprite is created and is able to be dragged around until the user lifts his finger. At this point, a physics body is then attached to the sprite so that it will fall to the bottom of the screen. However, when the sprite collides with another sprite/body I need it to stop being able to move. How do I check for a collision  between the sprite created and any other body/sprite (the walls and any others created)?

Comment: calculate the size and then see if it overlaps with another object's size?

Comment: I'd have to set up an array to calculate every objects position and size then, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for information on [Collision Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).

It's relatively simple to implement depending on your situation.
The simplest way would be to hold all your objects in an array/list and every time you move it you need to calculate its current position + area vs every other object.  This will be very inefficient, but if you have a small number of objects you are probably ok.

[Here](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson17/index.php) is the first collision detection tutorial I did.  It is for C, but the concepts are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather simple collision detection implemented in AndEngine. See method `collidesWith(IShape pOtherShape)` Someone improved it so that it works with transparent areas, search for pixel perfect collision detection.

You can also make use of the physics engine, see [sensor](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972).

Comment: The problem with this is that collidesWith() detects a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Although calculating the area would have worked, I was dealing with so many collisions that I needed a better way. It took quite a bit of time, but I finally figured out how to use a ContactListener (which was really what I was getting after. Why do these kinds of questions always get down voted when all someone really has to do is explain a bit to a novice???) Anyway, for reference to anyone else that might see this question, in your ContactListener, you can use code like this:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            if(fillerNum>-1 && contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData()!=null && contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData()!=null){
                String x1 = (String) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
                String x2 = (String) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
                if((x1.equals("fill")&&!x2.equals("dest"))||(x2.equals("fill"))&&!x1.equals("dest")){ //If a filler hits a stationary
                    //Log.e("Contact",x1 + " " + x2); 
                    createStationaryFiller();
                }
                if((x1.equals("dest")&&x2.equals("fill"))||(x1.equals("fill")&&x2.equals("dest"))){ //If a destroyer hits a filler
                    destroyFiller();
                }
            }
        }
```

Set growing bodies to have the user data "fill" and stationary ones to have the user data "stat". I also had some other bodies with the user data "dest". This way, you can see which two collides and react accordingly. Message me if you don't understand. *I* have no problem helping people new to this kind of thing.